# multiple arrays in 1 object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I need to have more than 1 array in the same object. But currently last array overrides all previous ones set and `push` doesn't work on objects.

```
var css = {};

$('input').each(function() {
    var selector = $(this).data('selector');
    var property = $(this).data('property');
    var hex = $(this).data('hex');
    css[selector] = [property, hex];
});
```

I can't use `integer` array keys because of the API limitation. Please help.

```
<input data-selector='body' data-property='background-color' data-hex='#ffffff'>
<input data-selector='body' data-property='color' data-hex='#ffffff'>
<input data-selector='body' data-property='border-width' data-hex='1px'>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make your object two levels deep, i.e.:

```
var css = {};

$('input').each(function() {
    var selector = $(this).data('selector');
    var property = $(this).data('property');
    var hex = $(this).data('hex');

    if (!css[selector]) {
        css[selector] = {};
    }
    css[selector][property] = hex;
});
```

With the given markup you would get:

```
css := {
  "body": {
    "background-color": "#ffffff",
    "color": "#ffffff",
    "border-width": "1px"
  }
};
```

Comment: replaced `if (!css[selector]...` with `css[selector] = (!css[selector]) ? {} : css[selector];`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can check for a truthy:

```
if (css[selector]) {
    css[selector].push([property, hex]);
else {
    css[selector] = [];
}
```

One other alternative is to use an object for the `property` / `hex` key value pair:

```
var el = {};
el['property'] = hex;
css[selector].push(el);
```

This makes it easier to access, like, `css.selector.property`.

Comment: I already tried it. I'm getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`. All 3 variables are set.

Comment: You need to define it as an array first: `css[selector] = []`.

Answer (score 0):

Is overriding because in every loop, you are creating an array with the same name that the previous loop created: `body`.

A better way to achieve what you want:

```
<input data-selector='body' data-property='background-color' data-hex='#ffffff'>
<input data-selector='body' data-property='color' data-hex='#ffffff'>
<input data-selector='body' data-property='border-width' data-hex='1px'>
```

JS:

```
var css = {};
css.body = [];

$('input').each(function(i) {
    var selector = $(this).data('selector');
    var property = $(this).data('property');
    var hex = $(this).data('hex');

    if (selector === 'body') {
      css.body.push([property, hex]);
    }
});
```

Assuming you have a input with the data-selector='footer', you can create a new array in the css object:

```
css.footer = [];
```

And them add a else if statement:

```
else if (selector === 'footer') {
  css.footer.push([property, hex]);
}
```

Is more maintainable like that.

---

Update:

If you need create the arrays depending on the user input, just use:

```
var css = {};

$('input').each(function(i) {
    var selector = $(this).data('selector');
    var property = $(this).data('property');
    var hex = $(this).data('hex');

    if (!css[selector]) {
      css[selector] = [];    
    } else {
      css[selector].push(property, hex);
    }

});
```

Comment: I can't define variables like `css.body`, because this is user input data.